# How to organize taxonomy terms for business directory in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to create a **business directory** using drupal. I have already created a proper content type for the entities but I'm a little confused about the taxonomy terms.

The companies should be organized according to their **type** and their **location (state)**.

Users should be able to browse companies by category. In each category there should be listed all available states and in each state there should be listed companies.

- Computers & Software

  - Alabama

    - list of companies
  - Georgia

    - list of companies
  - New York

    - list of companies
  - Florida

    - list of companies
- Business & Finance

  - Alabama

    - list of companies
  - Georgia

    - list of companies
  - New York

    - list of companies
  - Florida

    - list of companies

I thought that I should create **two vocabularies**, one for Company Category and one for Location. **OR** I could create **just one vocabulary** and insert all terms in that one.

Which approach would be the best? Could you pls help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two vocabularies. Don't mix category and location.

Whenever node would be created it would be selected both category and country for this node.

**[edit]**

Also, it is always be easy to make sorting both ways, first by category and then by country, or otherwise or both together.